twitter/x card not showing link preview
i have added a post of x developer's forum but i trust stackoverflow a lot more than x dev community so here i am posting my issue here.
My app’s twitter card preview is not showing up. while it shows up on LinkedIn and plenty of other ‘validator apps’ on the internet, it doesnt show image/title/description or anything on twitter tweet composer
PUBLIC URL of app (and specific post component):
https://urvin.finance/community/options/post/preferred-vendor-for-historic-options-data-97526b796c0145f6854e9cc8d95acbd5/
below is this link showing up my preview correctly on various platforms online:



my tech stack is Blazor .NET 8.
please note that im adding these tags dynamically in my component after fetching some data from DB, like post title, description, image, etc. i read twitter page on guidelines as well. also did curl to my public link. it shows all the tags with values.
Also, im adding these tags in pre-rendered format, NOT after the load of the app. so the tags are showing up correctly on LinkedIn but not on twitter/x
these are the meta tags that im adding dynamically in my component:
<meta property="og:image" content="@_imgUrl">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="@_imgUrl">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="@_title">
<meta property="og:description" content="@_shortDescription">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="@_title">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="@_shortDescription">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@@urvinfinance">
<meta property="og:url" content="@NavigationManager.Uri" />

Please guide me where if im missing something thanks.
